# How to convert a string that only has the month and year in a Pandas column into a datetime with another format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a dataset coming from a PDF file that contains a column for date in the following format: JAN2021, and I want to convert it into a datetime that only displays Month and Year, but as JAN-2021. I tried using the statement below but it did not work, is there any way I can do this with altering the data ( meaning without adding a day for that month as an alteration).

```
df2['MONTH1'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['MONTH1'], format="%mmm%YY")
```

any feedback/tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html

Comment: Use `format="%b%Y"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the month-year string (e.g.  `JAN2021`) to datetime format.  Then, use [`dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format the datetime objects to the required layout in `mmm-YYYY` (e.g `Jan-2021`), as follows:

(Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and column name is `Col1`):

```
df['Col_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], format='%b%Y').dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

      Col1   Col_new
0  JAN2021  Jan-2021
1  FEB2021  Feb-2021
2  MAR2021  Mar-2021
3  APR2021  Apr-2021
```

You have used an invalid format string `"%mmm%YY"` in your trial code.  For a complete list of valid format strings and their meaning, with examples, you can refer to the Python official document [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: thank you @SeaBean, I tried this one just now and I got this error: ValueError: time data 'APR21' does not match format '%b%YY' (match)

Comment: @WendyVelasquez   There is only one `Y` in the format string.  `'%b%Y'`  not `'%b%YY'`

Comment: I can show you the column  though, it has the following values   : 0     APR21
1     MAY21
2     JUN21
3     JUL21
4     AUG21
5     SEP21
6     OCT21
7     NOV21
8     DEC21
9     JAN22
10    FEB22
11    MAR22
12    APR22
13    MAY22
14    JUN22
15    JUL22
16    AUG22
17    SEP22
18    OCT22
19    NOV22

Comment: @WendyVelasquez   You have a mix of year on 2 digits and 4 digits ?

Comment: I tried changing the format of the year by adding the Y's as you mentioned above and still gives me that same error

Comment: @WendyVelasquez   If you year is in 2 digits rather than 4 digits in the question, you should use `'%b%y'`  instead

Comment: no, no.  the digit before the date is the numbering. I just copy the results and they come up with the numbering of the rows from the dataframe so you can ignore that.  the date given in the pdf file is just APR21, or JUN21

Comment: @WendyVelasquez   Yes, I understood.  Coz you have APR21 instead of APR2021, you should use `'%b%y'` instead.  Replace the `Y` with `y`

Comment: @WendyVelasquez   Welcome!  Pleased to help!   Happy programming and have a nice weekend :-)

Comment: @WendyVelasquez  I have edited to included a list of the valid format strings for your reference.  Please refer to the last paragraph and the link there.

Comment: Excelent @SeaBean, this will be a great reference for any other time :). Thank you!

Comment: @WendyVelasquez  Welcome!  Make good use of the doc  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Converting will add a day to the format.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

> pd.to_datetime looks for standard designations of the datetime
> component in the column names, including:
>
> **required**: year, month, day
>
> optional: hour, minute, second, millisecond, microsecond, nanosecond

Hence when converting you get a day (time is optional):

```
pd.to_datetime('JAN2021', format='%b%Y')
>> Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification with what I was using @MDR